# Change TTL from application on linux

Tags: c++, linux, networking, multicast

is there a way to set ttl from application? Using c++ rh, not using boost. In /etc/sysctl.conf file value net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl is not present, in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl written 64. I am sending traffic to multicast group and see TTL=1. Would like to increase it to 3. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure it per socket, using the IP_MULTICAST_TTL  setsockopt() flag. Take a look at the man pages for [ip](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html) and [setsockopt](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt).

Something like the following:

```
void setttl(int sock, uint8_t ttl)
{
    int ret = setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(uint8_t));
    if (ret != 0)
        printf("Failed to setsockopt(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
}
```

Comment: thanks Kristof! I am doing `setsockopt(m_socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&localInterface, sizeof(localInterface))` Will read and check your solution

Comment: Or right, I missed an option in my example. I didn't actually test it!